# How do I control what SAML metadata attributes generated for SP when working with SimpleSAML?

Tags: php, authentication, saml, saml-2.0

I'm asking this here after trying the SimpleSAML mailing list, checking the documentation, and spending a good amount of time reading through the SimpleSAML source code, and I'm hoping someone here might be able to help shed some light.

I'm still somewhat new to SimplesSAML, to please bear with me - it's entirely possible that I've made some fundamental misunderstandings about SAML or the library.

When defining the metadata send along to a relying service provider, how do you control the `xsi:type` of an `attributeValue` for an attribute you intend to include?

For example, let's say I need to generate xml like this to be accepted by a service provider, in an existing Attribute statement:

```
<saml2:Attribute 
  FriendlyName="Firstname"
  Name="MDS_firstname"
  NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified"
  xsi:type="saml2:AttributeType"
  >
  <saml2:AttributeValue
    ida:From="2013-08-16"
    ida:Language="en-GB"
    ida:To="2013-08-16"
    ida:Verified="true"
    xmlns:ida="http://www.some-organisation.org.uk/resource-library/ida/attributes"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:type="ida:PersonNameType"
    >
    Joe
  </saml2:AttributeValue>
</saml2:Attribute>
```

My understanding is that I'll need to write a specific auth module, like the provided examples, so generated the correct attributes, and possibly use an AttributeMap to take attributes of one form, and make sure they are mapped to a form that can be accepted.

So, I've put together a custom auth module as outlined [here](http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-modules).

Here's the code in `/lib` for the custom module, `sspmod_custom_Auth_Source_CustomAuth`:

```
  class sspmod_custom_Auth_Source_CustomAuth extends SimpleSAML_Auth_Source {

    // lots of code here

    public function finalStep(&$state) {

     // fetch information about user Joe, after authentication to p

      $attributes['MDS_firstname']   = array('Joe');

      $state['Attributes'] = $attributes;

    }

  }
```

Here's the code in www that is used as the endpoint for sending a user who's authenticated to, which exercises it:

```
  <?php

  /**
   * @file
   * The resume endpoint.
   * Assume a user is sent here with their state_id in the key `$_REQUEST['auth']`
   */


  $state_id = $_REQUEST['auth'];

  $state = SimpleSAML_Auth_State::loadState($state_id, sspmod_custom_Auth_Source_customAuth::STAGEID);

  $source_id = $state[sspmod_custom_Auth_Source_customAuth::AUTHID];

  // fetch original session
  $source = SimpleSAML_Auth_Source::getById($source_id);

  // add attributes to metadata
  $source->finalStep($state);

  // generate XML payload and send to service provider as usual
  SimpleSAML_Auth_Source::completeAuth($state);

  ?>
```

When I do this, I end up generating some xml the attribute payload, that looks a bit like this:

```
  <saml:Attribute Name="MDS_firstname"
    NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri"
    >
    <saml:AttributeValue 
      xsi:type="xs:string">
      Joe
    </saml:AttributeValue>
  </saml:Attribute>
```

How do I add extra attributes to the `saml:Attribute` here, so I can add the extra bits like `FriendlyName`, and so in?

And crucially, how do I change the `xsi:type` of the `saml:AttributeValue` here too?

I've looked at the documentation explaining auth procs and filters, but they don't seem to be concerned with changing the parts here I'm referring to.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Chris